# Two small Biblatex-APA questions

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm working on my MBA master thesis by using the package `biblatex-apa`. However by entering a reference to a powerpoint presentation I'm struggling. My university gives the example as follows for a ppt:

> Roberts, K. F. (1998). Federal regulations of chemicals in the environment [PowerPoint slides]. Retrieved from http://siri.uvm.edu/ppt/40hrenv/index.html

How I need to enter this in the .bib-file to achieve that [PowerPoint slides] between the title and retrieved from? Which type to use? I was experimenting with `@MISC` and `@INPROCEEDINGS` but would only get it like this:

```
@misc{DerSchweizerMarkt:2013vs,
author = {Ziegler, Philipp A},
title = {Der Schweizer Markt f{\"u}r Cloud Computing},
howpublished = {[Powerpoint Slides]},
year = {2013},
month = may,
url = {www.xyz.ch}
}
```

or

```
@inproceedings{DerSchweizerMarkt:2013vs,
author = {Ziegler, Philipp A},
title = {Der Schweizer Markt f{\"u}r Cloud Computing},
year = {2013},
month = may,
url = {www.xyz.ch}
}
```

yields for `@misc`

> Ziegler, P. A. (2013, May). Der Schweizer Markt für Cloud Computing.
>   [Powerpoint Slides]. Retrieved from www.xyz.ch

However the title is not *italic*. :(

with `@inproceedings`, it yields:

> Ziegler, P. A. (2013, May). Der Schweizer Markt für Cloud Computing.
>   Retrieved from www.xyz.ch

Anything else works perfectly fine and as intended. Which type would I need to do that? And if @misc is fine, why the title wouldn't be *italic*? I'm using Biber and PDFLateX to compile and have the newest versions of packages installed.

I'd appreciate some hints how I could achieve it.

Comment: It's not italic, because the title of a @misc-entry is declared with `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\iffieldequalstr{titleisdescription}{true}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}{{#1}\isdot}}` You have to modify this, switch to another entrytype (@data?), or be creative – depends on your document.

Comment: please provide an MWE for further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to save the entry as `unpublished` and PowerPoint Slides as `titleaddon` (title addons are printed with a different font than the title, while subtitles use the same font).

Here is a code…

```
\documentclass[12pt, british, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{pptinapa.bib}

\begin{document}

As we can see from \cite{schwei},…
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

… and the result:

[image]

If you don't want the month, don't write it in the entry.

Comment: With `biblatex` (and `biber`) there are few strategies to remove unwanted data instead of removing them from the `.bib` database, e..g., `\clearfield{month}` or using `\DeclareSourcemap`.